# How to generate code for the existential quantifier

Tags: isabelle

Here is a sample theory:

```
datatype ty = A | B | C

inductive test where
  "test A B"
| "test B C"

inductive test2 where
  "¬(∃z. test x z) ⟹ test2 x"

code_pred [show_modes] test .
code_pred [show_modes] test2 .

values "{x. test2 A}"
```

The generated code tries to enumerate over `ty`. And so it fails.

I'm tring to define an executable version of `test` predicate:

```
definition "test_ex x ≡ ∃y. test x y"

definition "test_ex_fun x ≡
  Predicate.singleton (λ_. False)
    (Predicate.map (λ_. True) (test_i_o x))"

lemma test_ex_code [code_abbrev, simp]:
  "test_ex_fun = test_ex"
  apply (intro ext)
  unfolding test_ex_def test_ex_fun_def Predicate.singleton_def
  apply (simp split: if_split)
```

But I can't prove the lemma. Could you suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existential quantifiers over an argument to an inductive predicate can be made executable by introducing another inductive predicate. For example:

```
inductive test2_aux where "test x z ==> test2_aux x"
inductive test2 where "~ test2_aux x ==> test2 x"
```

with appropriate `code_pred` statements. The free variable `z` in the premise of `test2_aux` acts like an existential. Since this transformation is canonical, `code_pred` has a preprocessor to do so:

```
code_pred [inductify] test2 .
```

does the job.

Comment: Thanks! It seems it works even without `[inductify]`.

Comment: inductify is needed only if you use your original definition without the intermediate predicate. In fact, inductify should precisely generate the intermediate predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `values` complains about the fact that `ty` is not of sort `enum`. So, in this particular case it is easiest to perform this instantiation.

```
instantiation ty :: enum
begin
definition enum_ty :: "ty list" where
  "enum_ty = [A,B,C]"  
definition "enum_all_ty f = list_all f [A,B,C]" 
definition "enum_ex_ty f = list_ex f [A,B,C]" 
instance
proof (intro_classes)
  let ?U = "UNIV :: ty set" 
  show id: "?U = set enum_class.enum" 
    unfolding enum_ty_def
    using ty.exhaust by auto
  fix P
  show "enum_class.enum_all P = Ball ?U P" 
    "enum_class.enum_ex P = Bex ?U P" 
    unfolding id enum_all_ty_def enum_ex_ty_def enum_ty_def by auto
  show "distinct (enum_class.enum :: ty list)" unfolding enum_ty_def by auto
qed
```

Afterwards, your `values`-command evaluates without problems.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I can't make it an instance of enum, because it's just a sample. An actual type isn't enumerable. I guess that an existence could be checked without enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the lemma is unprovable, and I should find another approach. But it can be proven as follows:

```
lemma test_ex_code [code_abbrev, simp]:
  "Predicate.singleton (λ_. False)
    (Predicate.map (λ_. True) (test_i_o x)) = (∃y. test x y)"
  apply (intro ext iffI)
  unfolding Predicate.singleton_def
  apply (simp_all split: if_split)
  apply (metis SUP1_E mem_Collect_eq pred.sel test_i_o_def)
  apply (intro conjI impI)
  apply (smt SUP1_E the_equality)
  apply (metis (full_types) SUP1_E SUP1_I mem_Collect_eq pred.sel test_i_o_def)
  done
```

The interesting thing is that the lemma structure and the proof structure seems to be independent of the concrete predicate. I guess there could be a general solution for any predicate.