# How to generate code for the uniqueness quantifier

Tags: isabelle

Here is a sample theory:

```
datatype ty = A | B | C

inductive test where
  "test A B"
| "test B B"
| "test B C"

inductive test2 where
  "The (λy. test x y) = y ⟹
   test2 x y"

code_pred [show_modes] test2 .

values "{x. test2 A x}"
```

The generated code tries to enumerate over `ty` and fails (as in [How to generate code for the existential quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879738/how-to-generate-code-for-the-existential-quantifier)). I can't make the data type an instance of `enum`.

The following code equation is generated:

```
test2_i_o ?xa ≡
  Predicate.bind (Predicate.single ?xa)
    (λxa. Predicate.bind (eq_i_o (The (test xa))) Predicate.single
```

I guess the error is raised because the equation contains `test` instead of `test_i_o`.

Could you suggest how to define such a predicate?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `The` operator in the inductive definition? As it is used in the example, there is not much point how it is used because the premise does not actually encode the fact that `test` has exactly one `y` for an `x`. So logically, `test2 C ...` holds for some `...`, but the logic does not tell you which value ... actually is.

Comment: My real use case is as follows. I define typing rules for an object-oriented programming language. An object model could define ambiguous operations and associations. In this case a programmer should specify operation argument types more precisely or should specify an oppposite end of the association. In any case the typing relation should return either an unique type or should not return type at all. You are right, my definition is wrong. Only `test2 A B` should hold. Could you suggest how to fix the definition?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've got it and updated my answer. The solution is based on techniques given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54891660/632199 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54972652/632199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. I should not use `The` operator. The predicate should be defined as follows. Code is generated fine with the `inductify` directive. An auxiliary predicate is generated in this case.

```
inductive test_uniq where
  "test x y ⟹
   (∀z. test x z ⟶ y = z) ⟹
   test_uniq x y"

code_pred [inductify, show_modes] test_uniq .
```

Alternatively one can define the auxiliary predicate explicitly:

```
inductive test_not_uniq where
  "test x z ⟹
   y ≠ z ⟹
   test_not_uniq x y"

inductive test_uniq where
  "test x y ⟹
   ¬ test_not_uniq x y ⟹
   test_uniq x y"

code_pred [show_modes] test_uniq .
```

---

**Old Wrong Answer**

Maybe It could help someone to generate code for `The` operator:

```
inductive test_ex where
  "The (λy. test x y) = y ⟹
   test_ex x y"

code_pred [show_modes] test .

lemma test_ex_code [code_pred_intro]:
  "Predicate.the (test_i_o x) = y ⟹
   test_ex x y"
  by (rule test_ex.intros) (simp add: Predicate.the_def test_i_o_def)

code_pred [show_modes] test_ex
  by (metis test_ex.cases test_ex_code)

inductive test2 where
  "test_ex x y ⟹
   test2 x y"

code_pred [show_modes] test2 .

values "{x. test2 A x}"
```

The code equation now contains `test_i_o` instead of `test`:

```
test_ex_i_o ?xa =
  Predicate.bind (Predicate.single ?xa)
    (λxa. Predicate.bind (eq_i_o (Predicate.the (test_i_o xa))) Predicate.single)
```